# mysql cast large number to char

Tags: mysql, mariadb

English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

Im using 5.5.38-MariaDB.
Mysql statement：

```
SELECT CAST(11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
AS char);
```

I get result is `99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999`,why?

Update:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT CAST(199999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 AS char);
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CAST(199999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 AS char) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 199999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999               |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT CAST(1999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 AS char);
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CAST(1999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 AS char) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                      |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1916 | Got overflow when converting '' to DECIMAL. Value truncated. |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `1111...` is parsed as a number, specifically as `DECIMAL(65, ...)`.  65 is the max; since the thing is bigger than that, it gave you 65 9's.  And it gave you a warning (that was probably ignored):

```
mysql> SELECT CAST(11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 AS CHAR) AS too_big;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| too_big                                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;                                                                               
+---------+------+---------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                               |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: '' |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What were you hoping to get?